# UrlConection not getting JSON response

Tags: android, multithreading, urlconnection

Hello all i am trying to open one URL using thread in activity on button click. i prepare one thread in `onClick` method. i wrote code. it is working but in response i am not getting response properly. It should return `JSON` response but its returning half string. My code is

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                url = new URL("https://api.metwit.com/v2/weather/?location_lat=22.03&location_lng=75.65");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    s.append(inputLine);

                }
                //br.close();
                Log.i("####$$$", s.toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s.toString());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }).start();

}
```

and i am getting response like

```
{"objects": [{"weather": {"status": "partly cloudy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 2.056, "wind_direction": 240.0, "temperature": 316.0, "humidity": 8}}, "timestamp": "2013-07-13T08:07:47.397932", "sun_altitude": 1.309306025505066, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [75.65, 22.03]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/partly_sunny"}, {"sources": ["weatherbug", "wwo", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "cloudy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 5, "wind_direction": 280, "temperature": 300, "humidity": 76}}, "timestamp": "2013-07-13T09:00:00", "sun_altitude": 1.0995509624481201, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [75.5859375, 21.97265625]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/cloudy"}, {"sources": ["weatherbug", "wwo", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "rainy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 5, "wind_direction": 280, "temperature": 300, "humidity": 76}}, "timestamp": "2013-07-13T12:00:00", "sun_altitude": 0.38399845361709595, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordin
```

what is wrong i am not getting.

Comment: Did you try to connect URL in your browser. What was the response ?

Comment: yes i tried in browser i got proper response.

Comment: i also tried using java code in different java  project i got proper response.

Comment: check whether ur button is correctly registested

Comment: @Android28:: i did not get it. if button is not registered how it can execute thread.

Comment: Are you checking the string in the log, or in the debugger?  The log will cut off all print statements after a certain length.

Comment: Are You observing any exception or any logs from android which might point to close of connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) to handle everything:

```
$.with(myButton).click(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        $.ajax(new AjaxOption().url("https://api.metwit.com/v2/weather/?location_lat=22.03&location_lng=75.65")
                               .type("GET")
                               .dataType("JSON")
                               .context(droidQuery.context())
                               .success(new Function() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                       JSONObject json = (JSONObject) params[0];
                                       droidQuery.toast(json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                       //If you want to simplify parsing, consider using:
                                       Map<String, ?> data = $.map(json);
                                       //TODO continue parsing
                                   }
                               })
                               .error(new Function() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                       droidQuery.alert("ERROR: " + (String) params[2]);
                                   }
                               }));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [android-query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) library, then it's easy.

```
     AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
     aq.ajax("https://api.metwit.com/v2/weather/?location_lat=22.03&location_lng=75.65",
             JSONObject.class,new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>(){

           @Override
           public void callback(String url, JSONObject object, AjaxStatus status) 
           {    
             String ret = object.toString();
             System.err.println(ret);
           }

     });
```

This solution works fine for me.